# Laravel unit test action with get parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4.2 and I am trying to run a unit test on an action with 'get' parameters.  I am failing trying to make this work.  How can I run a unit test that does a 'GET' to a controller action with 'GET' parameters?

```
public function testGetList()
{
  // test url "http://localhost/list" 
  $crawler = $this->action('GET', 'AppController@getList');
}

public function testGetListWithParams()
{
  // test url equivalent of "http://localhost/list?dateFrom=2015-01-01&dateTo=2015-12-31"
  $params = array('dateFrom'=>'2015-01-01','dateTo'=>'2015-12-31');
  $crawler = $this->action('GET', 'AppController@getList', array(), $params);
  // *** this is not working, the get parameters are not being passed. ***
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi third parameter must be your parameters and you set empty array
try

```
$crawler = $this->action('GET', 'AppController@getList', $params);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Turns our my issue existed because I was using '$_GET' instead of \Input::.



Doing:
    $crawler = $this->action('GET', 'AppController@getList', $params);



has the same effect as:
    $crawler = $this->action('GET', 'AppController@getList', array(), $params);



When grabbing the parameters using \Input::get().  I was using $_GET which does not recognize any of the parameters either way.